# Getting Forbidden error while running the jmeter script

Tags: jmeter

I an getting the error while running the script for the default magento checkout. 
The rest of the script is working properly but on checkout getting 403 error.
I am not getting why it is happening. So anyone can help me.

Comment: Please add the error details and the script you're using. Without this no one would be able to check or tell why the error is creeping up.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Response code 403 stands for [Forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403), the most likely your login attempt did not succeeded or application expects some parameter.

Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and inspect requests and responses to detect if they match your expectations.

For successful logging into a Magento application you need the following:

- Make sure you add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to your Test Plan
- Make sure you extract `form_key` parameter from the first response and pass it with the next request. It can be done with:

  - [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
  - [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
  - [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)

For instance, "good" CSS/JQuery Extractor configuration to get `form_key` value will look like:

[image: Magento form_key]

Refer extracted value as `${FORM_KEY}` where required.